# How to make navbar disappear when zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

When using auto hide top navigation of bootstrap 3, I noticed that when users use the native zoom on mobile, the top navigation also becomes very large. This leads to a pretty poor user experience, where the navigation obscures much of the content and ends up broken itself.

My question is; How to make navbar disappear when zoom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with [`devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio)

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
  var one =  Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100);
  //one will give you zoom percentage now here hide navigation 
});
```

live [output](https://jsfiddle.net/hf3bqnzw/)